# Installing fzf fuzzy finder offline

Tags: fzf

I'm behind a firewall and I have the fzf.tar.gz package which has the content of the git repo. How can I install fzf offline?

The install command ~/.fzf/install is reaching out to github.com. I'm on Redhat with no internet connection.

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

Answer (score 4):

This is just what I observed, I can't guarantee I didn't miss anything:

First, clone fzf to FZF_DIR on an online PC, then,

1. I'd suggest you to execute 'install' on an online PC to get necessary files
2. ~/.fzf/bin/fzf this one is downloaded by install script
3. ~/.fzf.bash this one is generated by install script
4. cp ~/.fzf/bin/fzf $FZF_DIR/bin
5. copy $FZF_DIR (with fzf binary in it) and .fzf.bash into your offline PC
6. ln -s $FZF_DIR ~/.fzf
7. source .fzf.bash in your .bashrc

Entire FZF_DIR is needed because it includes some other useful scripts sourced by .fzf.bash.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:

Just install `fzf` on a machine that can access network. And copy the `~/.fzf` directory into the target machine.